# Multiple counter in Smarty Template

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I have an array named listings.  How do I get multiple counter.  In the below given example i am getting number where condition is one.  I need one more counter to get number where condition is 0.  I want the result using the same foreach loop and do not want to create a new foreach loop.

```
{counter  start=1 print=0}
{foreach from=$listings item=listing}

    {if $listing.condition == '1'}
        {counter print=0}
    {/if}


{/foreach}

{counter}  // This givens me total count where condition is 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use name for each counter.

```
{counter name=condition_1 start=1 print=0}
{counter name=condition_0 start=1 print=0}
{foreach from=$listings item=listing}
    {if $listing.condition == '1'}
        {counter name=condition_1 print=0}
    {else}
        {counter name=condition_0 print=0}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
{counter name=condition_1}
{counter name=condition_0}
```

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.counter